# Creating a perceptron network when input array is large

Tags: matlab, neural-network, simulink

I need to create a perceptron which has two target values(0,1) and 21 input vectors. Each vector is 110592 in size. How do I call the "newp" function for this?

```
p=[I1,I2,I3,P1,P2,P3,Q1,Q2,Q3,R1,R2,R3,Z1,Z2,Z3,A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3];

t=[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

each vector I1,I2. etc are of size 1*110592.

if the perceptron has only two inputs, i can call the function as below.

```
newp([0 1;0 2],1); // which says 1st input is of range 0 to 1 and 2nd input is of range 0 2
```

SO the problem is how do i format my first argument when i have such a large vector input?

Comment: A perceptron usually takes one vector as input and outputs a value. It is the equivalent of thresholding the linear function **xw** + b where **x** is the input, **w** is a vector of weights, and b is the bias term. When you say 'input vectors' do you mean training examples?

Comment: Also what are p and t?